# How to user Wait Until Keyword Succeeds in Python File?

Tags: python, robotframework

is there any way to use Robot Framework Wait Until Keyword Succeeds in python file.

example:

```
form RPA.Browser.Selenium import Selenium
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

browser = Selenium()
builtin = BuiltIn()

*** Tasks ***
Task
   ***SOME CODE HERE***
   browser.click_element(SOMELOCATOR)
```

what i want to do is use RobotFramework builtin keyword **Wait Until Keyword Succeeds** here for **browser.click_element**

Comment: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/deb66734c27df11a44f6a43c92e1d8cf1f93bc85/src/robot/libraries/BuiltIn.py#L2231 - yes. BuiltIn() will return your running RF instance and then you are free to call anything from it..

Comment: @rasjani i tried that way but some error pops up showing ROBOTNOTFOUND error and something like no context.

Comment: Yes, you need to have robot framework running because plenty of RF libraries have code that explicitly requires a running robotframework instance (not just calling of BuiltIn()) ..   As alternative, you could use selenium's python API directly ..

Comment: so there is no way to run using the above method other than Selenium python API or Robot file

Comment: There are always "ways" but nobody has implemented them or explaining how one would mock a running instance of RF would fall into category of "Depends on how much you are willing to pay because that needs some serious research" ..